# Exclude a group if condition of another column isn't met

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, select, group-by

This is a simplified example of what I'm dealing with. I'm creating a temp table (a) by joining a different temp table with a table stored in the database. I have the following output for temp table (a):

| name | date | dollars |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2022-06-01 | $500 |
| A | 2022-05-01 | $250 |
| A | 2022-04-01 | $100 |
| A | 2022-03-01 | $475 |
| B | 2022-06-01 | $180 |
| B | 2022-05-01 | $30 |
| B | 2022-04-01 | $360 |
| ... | ... | ... |

My ultimate goal is to sum 'dollars' and group by 'name'. However, I only want my final output to include 'name' if the earliest recorded date for the group is more than 3 months from today's date. So in the case above, I would want to include 'A' and sum the 'dollars' together, but I want to exclude B because it does not meet my condition. How can I do that?

This is what I want my final output to be;

| name | date | dollars |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2022-06-01 | $1375 |
| ... | 2022-06-01 | ... |

Comment: `having min(date) < dateadd(month, -3, getdate())` It's not clear exactly how you define your cutoff. Perhaps even `having count(*) > 3` would be sufficient.

Comment: @shawnt00 `having count(*) > 3` would only work if there's only one record per month

Comment: @Schmiel which is where the word "perhaps" comes in.

Comment: @shawnt00 for background, I have monthly data (end of month) available. The earliest data point is 9/30/2021 and most recent is 5/31/2022. The first query (min (date)) results in the the last 2 months of data missing - the most recent data point in the output is 2/28/2022. The second query (count(*)>3) results in the earliest 3 data points missing - the earliest data point in the output is 12/31/2021. Any ideas on why that would be?

Comment: @shawnt00 As for my cutoff, I am grouping "name" together and want to exclude groups that do not have at least 3 months of data of available. For example as of today, I would want to exclude any "name" groups that do not have data available prior to 02/28/2022 (my data becomes available on the last day of the month). If I'm running my query on 07/01/2022, I would exclude groups that have 03/31/2022 as the earliest data point. I hope that clarifies.

Comment: You should make some sample output with more than one row of output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the case instruction like this

```
SELECT  
    case 
        when min(dt) <= dateadd(month,-3,getdate()) then (select name FROM example where name = e.name group by name)
    else null
    end as name,
    max(dt),
    case 
        when min(dt) <= dateadd(month,-3,getdate()) then (select sum(dollars) FROM example where name = e.name group by name)
        else null
    end as dollars          
from 
    example e
group by 
    name
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
create table #temp1 
(
 name char(1),
 date datetime,
 dollars int
);

insert into #temp1 (name,date,dollars) select 'A','06/01/2022',500
insert into #temp1 (name,date,dollars) select 'A','05/01/2022',250
insert into #temp1 (name,date,dollars) select 'A','04/01/2022',100
insert into #temp1 (name,date,dollars) select 'A','03/01/2022',475
insert into #temp1 (name,date,dollars) select 'B','06/01/2022',180
insert into #temp1 (name,date,dollars) select 'B','05/01/2022',30
insert into #temp1 (name,date,dollars) select 'B','04/01/2022',360

with cte
as
(
select name,min(date) as date1,GETDATE() as date2,sum(dollars) as dollars
from #temp1
group by name
having min(date)<DATEADD(month,-3,getdate()))

select name,date2 as date,dollars 
from cte
```

Could this work?

Comment: could this work?

Answer (score 0):

You want to report monthly totals for all months but only for those names with data going back more than three months.

```
with data as (
    <your main data here>
), aggregated as (
    select name, max(date) as date, sum(dollars) as dollars,
        min(max(date)) over (partition by name) as first_date,
        count(*) over (partition by name) as month_count
    from data
    group by name
)
select name, date, dollars, first_date, month_count
from aggregated
where first_date < dateadd(month, -3, getdate());
```

Or

```
with data as (
    <your main data here>
)
select name, max(date) as date, sum(dollars) as dollars
from data d1
where exists (
    select 1 from data d2
    where d2.name = d1.name and d2.date < dateadd(month, -3, getdate())
)
group by name;
```